# Why is the map automatically zooming in after I manually moved it?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotation

I am having a problem with the map within my app. I set the starting location as the center of the users location, but when I go to move the map around, it doesn't allow me to and/or moves automatically back to the center.

I have `userTrackingMode` set to `.follow`. I can't really think of anything else that might be causing this to happen, although I am fairly new to Xcode and Swift.

Here is where I think the problem occurs:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct UberMapViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    let mapView = MKMapView()
    let locationManager = LocationManager()
    
    @EnvironmentObject var locationViewModel: LocationSearchViewModel
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
        mapView.isRotateEnabled = false
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        mapView.userTrackingMode = .follow
        
        return mapView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
        if let coordinate = locationViewModel.selectedLocationCoordinate {
            context.coordinator.addAndSelectAnnotation(withCoordinate: coordinate)
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> MapCoordinator {
        return MapCoordinator(parent: self)
    }
}

extension UberMapViewRepresentable {
    
    class MapCoordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
        
        // MARK: - Properties
        
        let parent: UberMapViewRepresentable
        
        // MARK: - Lifecycle
        
        init(parent: UberMapViewRepresentable) {
            self.parent = parent
            super.init()
        }
        
        // MARK: - MKMapViewDelegate
        
        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion(
                center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation.coordinate.longitude),
                span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05)
            )
            
            parent.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        }
        
        // MARK: - Helpers
        
        func addAndSelectAnnotation(withCoordinate coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
            parent.mapView.removeAnnotations(parent.mapView.annotations)
            let anno = MKPointAnnotation()
            anno.coordinate = coordinate
            parent.mapView.addAnnotation(anno)
            parent.mapView.selectAnnotation(anno, animated: true)
            
            parent.mapView.showAnnotations(parent.mapView.annotations, animated: true)
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You have code that updates the map’s center on location updates.

Comment: @HangarRash What do you think I need to do to fix it?

Comment: You either force the map to keep centered or you let the user move the map around.